# PHP Time Format Issue

Tags: php, datetime

PHP time format generate different results when spaces included

```
 date('h:i A',strtotime('05:45 AM')); //05:45AM
 date('h:i A',strtotime('05 : 45 AM')); // 01:00 AM
```

Here is the [result](http://3v4l.org/kERpa)

Spaces works in older version of PHP and it is failing in PHP Version above 5.0.5;
I wanted to check why this is not allowed with new version

Comment: Spaces are not valid in time formats so if you use them you should expect incorrect results.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You could however strip out the spaces and *then* parse the time using strtotime().

Comment: because it is not valid time for PHP.It will always show the same time 01:00 AM whatever you enter with space

Comment: I noted different results showing in time.I wanted confirm this is not a bug in newer version

Comment: So the "bug" is in older PHP versions that _allowed_ the extra spaces? Is there a valid reason to ignore (or **not** ignore) these spaces? Granted, it will not be common to see times written with extra spaces, but should they be penalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, its not a valid time format with the spaces.

Check this resource for strtotime: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

And also check this page for date/time formats: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php